# Loading UIImage from NSData causing jerky UITableView scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdata

I am having getting my tableview to scroll smoothly when loading in images from NSData.

Some background ... I'm storing image NSData in Core Data (using the 'allows external storage' option so i dont think storing the URLs or something like that is the solution here). Further, I am storing two types of data, one high res with UIImagePNGRepresentation, and one low res with UIImageJPGRepresentation. I am loading in the low res images for my table view. The image property on the entry object is not stored in core data, its set after the fact. Here is how I am doing it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        

    DMLogTableViewCell *cell = (DMLogTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LogCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setGradients:@[[UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor lightTextColor]]];
    Entry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *entryImage = entry.image;

    if (entryImage)
        cell.rightImageView.image = entryImage;
    else {
        NSOperationQueue *oQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [oQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.photo.lowResImageData];
            if (!image) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage.png"];
            entry.image = image;
        }];
        [oQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
                DMLogTableViewCell *cell = (DMLogTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.rightImageView.image = entry.image;
            }];
        }];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to run more smoothly? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This has gotten me much closer, but there is still a little bit of jerkiness . . . 
(within cellForRowAtIndexPath)

```
    UIImage *entryImage = entry.image;

    if (entryImage)
        cell.rightImageView.image = entryImage;
    else {
        [self.imageQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.photo.lowResImageData];
            if (!image) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bills_moduleIcon.png"];
            entry.image = image;
            [entry.image preload];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
                DMLogTableViewCell *cell = (DMLogTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.rightImageView.image = entry.image;
            }];
        }];
    }
```

that preload method is in a cateogory on UIImageView and looks like this:

```
- (void)preload
{
    CGImageRef ref = self.CGImage;
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(ref);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(ref);
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * 4, space, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), ref);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}
```

I think my next plan of attack is to mess around with the size of the images stored (as mentioned in the comments) or perhaps trying to not update the imageViews while the table is scrolling. Any thoughts on those two methods are much appreciated! ill check back in when i've done that

**UPDATE 2**
Many many thanks for everyone who helped me out with this! Here was the final solution (in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    if (entryImage)
        cell.rightImageView.image = entryImage;
    else {
        [self.imageQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.photo.lowResImageData];
            if (!image) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bills_moduleIcon.png"];
            entry.image = [image scaleToSize:cell.rightImageView.frame.size];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
                DMLogTableViewCell *cell = (DMLogTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.rightImageView.image = entry.image;                
            }];
        }];
    }
```

adding a new category method to UIImage:

```
-(UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Scrolling is now perfectly smooth. Awesome

Comment: Appreciate the help. Resizing was indeed the final issue messing with the scroll performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. I'd want to see how much time these two lines are taking:

   ```
   Entry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   UIImage *entryImage = entry.image;
   ```

   While I gather that `entry.image` is a cached image, I wouldn't be so confident that `objectAtIndexPath:indexPath` isn't actually retrieving the `NSData` from Core Data (which is a good portion of the performance issue in storing images in a local database rather than the file system). I'd be inclined to do this in the background queue.
2. I don't understand why you're adding two operations to `oQueue` (which could operate concurrently!). It should just be as follows, so you don't try to dispatch to main queue until the image is retrieved:

   ```
   [oQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.photo.lowResImageData];
       if (!image) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage.png"];
       entry.image = image;

       [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
           DMLogTableViewCell *cell = (DMLogTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           cell.rightImageView.image = entry.image;
       }];
   }];
   ```
3. It's probably not material, but you really shouldn't create a new `NSOperationQueue` for each cell. You should define a class property that is a `NSOperationQueue`, initialize it in `viewDidLoad`, and then use that queue in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It's not material, I'm sure, but it's not worth the overhead of creating a queue for each row of your table. (And if you ever go to server-based image retrieval, using a single queue is very important so you can control the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.)

Comment: +1, Very good points.  Another possible issue is when he sets the image view's image.  If the image is not *stored on the disk* at the same size as it is being displayed, it will also cause choppiness because the image is scaled to the correct size every time.  Lots of code is around (here on SO and on Google) which "resizes" an image but when you store it to disk it is saving the entire image and not the thumbnail.

Comment: i am thinking this is a good thing to investigate next ... i am getting closer but the scrolling is still not perfectly smooth ... updating to show my progress now

Answer (score 0):

UIImage wont actually do the decode until it needs to draw the image, so its actually happening on the main thread when you assign the image to the image view.

I have a UIImage category which will force the image to be decoded (which you should run on a background thread) here : https://github.com/tonymillion/TMDiskCache

Comment: In addition I do exactly this process (storing a low-res jpg NSData in a coredata object which is displayed while the main image is being downloaded)